# mathematica Sum of functions

Tags: function, sum, wolfram-mathematica

I want to build a function in the following way:

```
f[x_] := 0;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
    g[x_] := 0; 
    For[k = 1, k <= i, k++,
            g ^:= g[#]*(# - X[[k]]) &;
            g[x_] = g;
        ]
    f ^:= f[#] + Q[[1, i]]*g[#];
    f[x_] = f;
```

So I get a polynomial 
Q_11 * (x-x_1) + Q_12 * (x-x_1) * (x-2x_2) ...

This is the latest version I have, but it does not work. The problem is that I have to add functions (I found some posts where it is done) but I have to save the new function so I can use it again. 
Does someone know what to do?

Thanks!

Marius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant make head or tail of your code but you can readily construct that result just like this:

```
 qlist = Array[q, {10, 10}];
 xlist = Array[x, 10];
 poly[n_] := Sum[ qlist[[1, j]] Product[ (x - xlist[[i]] ), {i, j}] , {j, 3}]
 poly[3]
```

> ```
> q[1, 1] (x - x[1]) + q[1, 2] (x - x[1]) (x - x[2]) + 
>        q[1, 3] (x - x[1]) (x - x[2]) (x - x[3])
> ```

If you really need help using `UpSetDelayed` you should pose a more simple / specific question ( ie without the `For` loops. )